# Will Twilio help us test demo verification codes via SMS?

Tags: twilio, sms

Will Twilio help us test demo verification codes via SMS?
The verification code is typically a 4 digit or a 6 digit numerical number, as part of the testing , the SMS verification code must be extracted from the mobile and then inserted in my web application and proceed with the flow.

Is there any documentation or help available in this regard?

We tried and we only getting a blank message

Comment: Can you please share more context? Are you trying to test whether Twilio sent the code or are you planning to receive a OTP code via a Twilio number? Please also describe what you've done so far and the issue you encountered.